# Update Store Procedure not working

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a simple stored procedure that I am executing on a table I created. When I execute the update statement by itself with hard coded parameters it works, but the procedure doesn't update when executed. It returns a "Command completed successfully" but no rows affected. I check the data and it hasn't changed either.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
alter PROCEDURE uspUpdatePrices 
    @adjustment AS float, 
    @itemNumber AS VarChar
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE [NIMEH].[dbo].[TestIV00108]
    SET UOMPRICE = @adjustment
    WHERE RTRIM(ITEMNMBR) = @itemNumber
END
GO
```

Comment: Define a length of your parameter. For instance `@itemNumber AS VarChar(100)`

Comment: The query you have posted is for **altering** the procedure - not for executing!
Are you sure you are running the procedure the correct way?

Comment: Thats just the procedure itself, not the execution

Answer (score 0):

Since in the where clause comparison is between two string variables make sure values in the parameter is exactly same as the value in row.

If white space present at start or end apply both ltrim and rtrim to column value.

Also specify length of varchar column as default length is 30 in sql server which may result in overflow.

Note - making operation on the table column makes it not searchable hence index can not be used properly, it's better to make operation on the parameter value